# Repeated Form Field in WordPress Widget?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, widget

I am building a plugin for WordPress. My main goal is to strictly build a custom widget and try to avoid custom post type.

I tried this plugin: [repeated entries widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/repeater-entries-widget/) and it adds more entries when we click on the "Add Row" button. However, it somehow saves the input without me clicking the default "Save" button of the widget.

My question is: Is dynamic form in WordPress widget possible? Is there a way to have dynamic form, and then only to save the data when the user clicks on the default "save" button?

Comment: I found a solution to my question here: [Is dynamic forms/entries possible in Widget?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257405/is-dynamic-forms-entries-possible-in-widget?noredirect=1#comment382315_257405)

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with PHP take a look at https://carbonfields.net you can create any type of custom meta boxes / widgets / theme options etc...

**widgets:** https://docs.carbonfields.net/#/containers/widgets
**repeater fields** https://docs.carbonfields.net/#/fields/complex

Another option would be Advanced Custom Fields the pro version that has support for repeater fields and other cool stuff.

Otherwise the solution you found here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257405/is-dynamic-forms-entries-possible-in-widget?noredirect=1#comment382315_257405 looks good :)